# How to Get the Color From an Image when it loads?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, colors, flex4

i'm loading a SWF image file. Each time the image loads, I want the color of image. 
I used blendMode.INVERT , it changes the color of image to black. Just like is there any way to get the image color with few line of code in Flex.

```
var imag1:Image=currentReference.getChildAt(0) as Image;
imag1.blendMode = BlendMode.INVERT;
Alert.show("Image Path-->  "+ imag1.source + "  Color-->  "+ imag1.blendMode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html). It should help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitmapData - getPixel() method
Something like:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete, false, 0,   true);
loader.load(new URLRequest('imageName.jpg'));

var loadedImageIndexColours:Vector.<uint>;

function onImageLoadComplete( event:Event ):void
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loadedImageIndexColours = getIndexColours(Bitmap(loader.contentLoaderInfo.content).bitmapData);
    loader = null;
    trace(loadedImageIndexColours);
}

function getIndexColours(bitmapData:BitmapData, unique:Boolean = true):Vector.<uint>
{
    var colors:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();

    for (var x:int = 0; x < bitmapData.width; x++)
    {
        for (var y:int = 0; y < bitmapData.height; y++)
        {
            colors.push(bitmapData.getPixel(x, y));
        }
    }

    return (unique) ? removeDuplicates(colors) : colors;
}

function removeDuplicates(inVector:Vector.<uint>):Vector.<uint>
{
    return inVector.filter(_removeDuplicatesFilter);
}

function _removeDuplicatesFilter(e:uint, i:int, inVector:Vector.<uint>):Boolean
{
    return (i == 0) ? true : inVector.lastIndexOf(e, i - 1) == -1;
}
```